Nested \int_step_inline:nn
The code below has two tested \int_step_inline:nn commands. I assumed that to access the stepped variables I would need to use ##1 and ###1, respectively, but this throws the error:

Illegal parameter number in definition of \__int_map_1:w.

Is there a way to nest these commands? I suspect that the answer is that these inline commands are not designed to be nested (the interface3 manual describes them as shortcuts that are provided for code clarity), so I should be using an explicit loop command instead. This is what I have done in the actual code I am writing, but I wanted to double check that I am not misunderstanding something.
Here's the code:
\documentclass{amsart}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\test{ m m }
{
    \int_step_inline:nn {#1}
    {
        \int_step_inline:nn {#2} {##1-###1} \\
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

   \test{3}{4}

\end{document}


No, the number is powers of 2: 1, 2, 4...

Ah, right, so it should be ####1. Thank you! I vaguely remember this now, but I clearly forgot . If you want to convert your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

In general when nesting function definitions etc where we want to refer to arguments from each level, we need to double the number of # at each level, so #1, ##1, ####1 etc
